# how to resolve this problem on npm start

Tags: 12.10

```
nikhil@nikhil-HP-2000-Notebook-PC:~$ npm start
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, open '/home/nikhil/package.json'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
npm ERR! including the npm and node versions, at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>

npm ERR! System Linux 3.5.0-51-generic
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "start"
npm ERR! cwd /home/nikhil
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.28
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.26
npm ERR! path /home/nikhil/package.json
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/nikhil/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Answer (score 2):

Error code ENOENT mean "no such file or directory".

Check your installation if you have the file `/home/nikhil/package.json` present and accessible by the application.

From this post in [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17130020/retrieving-node-js-module-from-github-error-enoent-open-package-package-json), it has been recommended also to do `npm init` to initialize and create a valid `package.json` file.